# How to apply icons to links using css?

Tags: css

i was wondering how can i add images to links with css that is compatible across FF, IE and Opera browsers?

Comment: Do you want an icon next to the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background to your link icon and the padding to the width of your icon.

```
a { 
   padding-left: 10px;
   background: transparent url(link_icon.png) no-repeat center left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a [background-image](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-image.asp) to the link.

You can use margins, padding, and [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp) to change where your background image is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
a {
   display:block;
   width:10px;
   height:10px;
   background:url(/images/image.png) 0 top;
   padding-left:5px
  }
```

Background-position your x coordinate at 0 and then pad the left side of the a tag